# Is right shift undefined behavior if the count is larger than the width of the type?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, standards, undefined-behavior

I just checked the *C++* standard. It seems the following code should NOT be [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
unsigned int val = 0x0FFFFFFF;
unsigned int res = val >> 34;  // res should be 0 by C++ standard,
                               // but GCC gives warning and res is 67108863
```

And from the standard:

> The value of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. **If E1
>   has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a non-negative
>   value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
>   E1/2^E2.** If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting
>   value is implementation-deﬁned.

According to the standard, since 34 is NOT an negative number, the variable `res` will be 0.

GCC gives the following warning for the code snippet, and `res` is `67108863`:

> warning: right shift count >= width of type

I also checked the assembly code emitted by GCC. It just calls `SHRL`, and the Intel instruction document for SHRL, the `res` is not ZERO.

So does that mean GCC doesn't implement the standard behavior on Intel platform?

Comment: The standard quote you gave talks about the first operand, i.e. `val`, not the `34`.

Comment: @ChristianRau, you are correct.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) in section `5.8` *Shift operators* in paragraph *1* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **The behavior is undefined if the right operand** is negative, or **greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand**.

So if *unsigned int* is `32 bits` or less then this is undefined which is exactly the warning that `gcc` is giving you.

Comment: @Zaibis: Yes, GCC is able to compile C++.  It is a common misconception that GCC is (only) a C compiler, or that G++ is a different compiler.

Comment: @Zaibis: GCC is a toolchain; it has compilers (and linkers and lots of other things) for both C and C++.

Answer (score 21):

To explain exactly what happens: 
The compiler will load `34` into a register, and then your constant in another register, and perform a right shift operation with those two registers. The x86 processor performs a "shiftcount % bits" on the shift value, meaning that you get a right-shift by 2.

And since 0x0FFFFFFF (268435455 decimal) divided by 4 = 67108863, that's the result you see.

If you had a different processor, for example a PowerPC (I think), it may well give you zero.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was doing the last days a lot with working on PPC and shifting, and gcc wasn't able to represent on PPC32 a 32bit shift of an integer. So are you sure about your statement refering to PPC? (I did work with C source but if the CPU arch isn't able to do so, the language shouldn't be relevant, shoudl it?)

Comment: @Zaibis GCC is a portable compiler, and there is no reason to disable the code inside GCC that warns for shifts by a number too large when it is emitting code for a PowerPC. But I can assure you that the PowerPC processor does have the couple of additional transistors that allow the assembly instruction for right-shift to produce the expected result when shifting by 34.

Comment: @dhein: ARM might be a better example, then.  It does saturate shift counts, i.e. `lsr r0, r0, r1` will shift out all the bits if `r1` is 32 or higher.  ARM can also encode immediate shifts with a count greater than 31, for example `lsr r0, r0, #32` does assemble.  (All mainstream 32-bit ISAs have immediate shifts; the compiler won't actually load `34` into a register unless you do `int count = 34;`  / `val <<= count;` in a debug build.)