# c++ - warning: right shift count >= width of type on 32 bit machine

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, bit-shift, unsigned-integer

I have the following function:

```
void func(unsigned long v)
{
  char max_byte = 0xFF;
  char buffer[8];

  buffer[0] = static_cast<char>((v)       & max_byte);
  buffer[1] = static_cast<char>((v >> 8)  & max_byte);
  buffer[2] = static_cast<char>((v >> 16) & max_byte);
  buffer[3] = static_cast<char>((v >> 24) & max_byte);
  buffer[4] = static_cast<char>((v >> 32) & max_byte);
  buffer[5] = static_cast<char>((v >> 40) & max_byte);
  buffer[6] = static_cast<char>((v >> 48) & max_byte);
  buffer[7] = static_cast<char>((v >> 56) & max_byte);
}
```

which takes an `unsigned long` argument and insert its 8 bytes to `char` buffer ( don't try to figure out why. it is a concise version of a meaningful function).

This code compiles well on 64 bit but on 32 bit I get the following warning:

```
warning: right shift count >= width of type
```

referring to lines:

```
  buffer[4] = static_cast<char>((v >> 32) & max_byte);
  buffer[5] = static_cast<char>((v >> 40) & max_byte);
  buffer[6] = static_cast<char>((v >> 48) & max_byte);
  buffer[7] = static_cast<char>((v >> 56) & max_byte);
```

I think I understand the warning but I'm not sure what should I do to be able to compile it smoothly on 32 bit as well.

Comment: Yes, it is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918256/is-right-shift-undefined-behavior-if-the-count-is-larger-than-the-width-of-the-t/18918340#18918340) to perform a shift with a width greater or equal to number of bits.

Comment: What is the length of `unsigned long` on the 32-bit-system?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I understand that, but what is the solution. `unsigned long` is 64 bit in length and I need to process it correctly.

Comment: Let's speak on shift operators <<, >> - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0142/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unsigned long` is only guaranteed to have 32 bits. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). You need to use `unsigned long long` to have 64 bits guaranteed.

Even better would be to use a [fixed width integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), i.e. `uint64_t`. They are defined in header `<cstdint>` (or `<stdint.h>`).

Comment: "also in earlier versions of C++" - only if your library/compiler has non-standard extensions. They weren't standard until C++11.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [fixed-width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).  In this case, you want `std::uint64_t`.

Comment: Or at least *try*, there is no requirement on the implementation to provide those :) But yes, this is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

When writing code that depends on integer size, you really, really need to be using `<stdint.h>`.

```
#include <stdint.h>

void func(uint64_t v)
{
  static const uint8_t max_byte = 0xFF; // Let the compiler hardcode this constant.
  uint8_t buffer[8];

  buffer[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v)       & max_byte);
  buffer[1] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 8)  & max_byte);
  buffer[2] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 16) & max_byte);
  buffer[3] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 24) & max_byte);
  buffer[4] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 32) & max_byte);
  buffer[5] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 40) & max_byte);
  buffer[6] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 48) & max_byte);
  buffer[7] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 56) & max_byte);
}
```

Comment: Today's not my day. Modem lost connection right as I was trying to post. >_<

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong with the assumption that none of the answers truly gets to the point of this question, therefore here goes.

Compiling as a 64bit binary a long is defined as a 64bit value (or 8 bytes), whereas a 32 bit binary a long is the same as an int which is 32 bits or 4 bytes.

There are several solutions to the problem:
1. redefine the parameter to a long long or an int64 as suggested in other responses.
2. add a preprocessor define to block out the offending bit operations. Such as...

```
#ifdef __LP64__
buffer[4] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 32) & max_byte);
buffer[5] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 40) & max_byte);
buffer[6] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 48) & max_byte);
buffer[7] = static_cast<uint8_t>((v >> 56) & max_byte);
#endif
```

This will ensure that a long is processed according to the processors architecture and not forcing a long to always be 64 bits.
3. Using a union would accomplish the same end result too, for the code provided

```
void func(unsigned long v)
{
    union {
        unsigned long long  ival;
        unsigned char       cval[8];
    } a;

    a.ival = v;
}
```

of course if you use c++ then you can store any basic datatype in a similar fashion by modifying the above as follows:

```
template<class I>
void func(I v) {
    union {
        unsigned long long  ival;
        unsigned char       cval[8];
        I                   val;
    } a;

    a.val = v;
}
```