# Why the following two programs yield different outputs? (C++, bit operation, VS 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, language-lawyer, bit, undefined-behavior

Program 1:

```
int x = 4 ^ (4>>32);
cout << x << endl;
```

Output is 4

Program 2:

```
int x = 4;
int y = x ^ (x>>32);
cout << y << endl;
```

Output is 0

Comment: Assuming `int` is 32-bit on your platform, a shift of 32-bit results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: If int is 32 bit then right shifting by [32 or more is undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918256/is-right-shift-undefined-behavior-if-the-count-is-larger-than-the-width-of-the-t/18918340#18918340)

Comment: Possible duplicate above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code-snippets induce undefined behavior if `int` has 32 bit or less. [expr.shift]/1:

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater
>   than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

Hence an implementation is not in any way obliged to provide consistent results.