# Strange behavior of bit-shift

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Can't understand behavior of this bit shift:

```
int container = 1;

cout<<(container>>32)<<endl;
```

If it's logical shift the output should be 0, but it's 1 instead, as if it was cyclic shift. When looking at disassembly I see that command used is SAR. Please explain this behavior to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918256/is-right-shift-undefined-behavior-if-the-count-is-larger-than-the-width-of-the-t

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about this.  Did you try the `-Wall` option?

Comment: Visual Studio produces a warning. On X86 / X64, the 32 bit operand shift instructions only use the bottom 5 bits of the count, in this case: 32&0x1f == 0. You could have used container >>= 31; container >>= 1; and that would work (should produce  0 or -1 on X86 / X64).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shifted a 32-bit number by 32, which results in undefined behavior, and the resulting 1 is a coincidence.

Comment: Yes it's undefined behavoir. But I tried it with different values, on different compilers and it's allways the same.

Comment: And that means it's not undefined behaviour because ...? I would try it on a different architecture and see what happens.

Comment: I don't say it's not undefined behaviour. I'm just trying to understand why it happens like that.

Comment: The compiler tries by remainder (reminder on the division of number-of-shifts per length-of-operand) if the number of shifts is greater than operand length

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826523/undoing-shifts-without-truncating/49826656#49826656