# Shift Operation in C++

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

Why this code prints two different numbers for `f1` and `f2`?:

```
int main() {  
  int a = 32;
  int f1 = (0xffffffff << a); 
  int f2 = (0xffffffff << 32);

  std::cout << f1 << std::endl;  // print -1
  std::cout << f2 << std::endl;  // print 0
}
```

For f2, I get this warning but nothing for f1:

> warning: left shift count >= width of type

I am using g++ 4.4.7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918256/is-right-shift-undefined-behavior-if-the-count-is-larger-than-the-width-of-the-t/18918340#18918340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer would be you are [invoking undefined behavior when shifting by width of type or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18918340/1708801).

The longer answer is that for the second case gcc can constant fold the expression and just moves in a zero (*[see it live on godbolt](http://goo.gl/mJAD96)*):

```
movl    $0, -28(%rbp)   #, f2
```

while in the first case it actually performs the shift:

```
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax # a, tmp63
movl    $-1, %edx   #, tmp64
movl    %edx, %ebx  # tmp64,
movl    %eax, %ecx  #,
sall    %cl, %ebx   #,
movl    %ebx, %eax  #, D.21248
movl    %eax, -24(%rbp) # D.21248, f1
```

Since we are invoking undefined behavior we can have no expectations for the result. Inconsistent answers to what seemingly should provide the same answer is perfectly acceptable undefined behavior.

Comment: nice answer.. godbolt is cool!

Answer (score 1):

The result of

```
0xffffffff << 32
```

is

```
18446744069414584320
```

which is far larger then `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`

If your system represents `int` as 4 bytes, then the above value is

```
2147483647
```

[Signed overflow is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c) so both exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: op's asking why the behavior's different for the two versions, even though `a` is also 32.

Comment: I expect to get 0 for both. for f2, it's correct, I get 0. But I get -1 for f1 which uses a instead of 32.

Comment: @Nargesoo You should not *expect* anything, your code exhibits undefined behavior, so the result is unspecified. The fact that you consider an output of `0` to be "correct" doesn't agree with the C++ standard.

Comment: The result of the shift is undefined so we can't really talk about signed overflow here, this also does not explain the differing results.