# Is shifting std::bitset<N> more than N positions undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, bit-shift

As discussed in [Is right shift undefined behavior if the count is larger than the width of the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918256/is-right-shift-undefined-behavior-if-the-count-is-larger-than-the-width-of-the-t), shifting a value is undefined if the number of bit shifts exceeds the effective operand size.

Thus, in the following, the value of `bar` is undefined:

```
uint32_t foo = 123;
uint32_t bar = (foo >> 33);
```

Are such shift operations well defined for `std::bitset`? As in:

```
std::bitset<32> foo(123);
std::bitset<32> bar(foo >> 33);
```

And in which official document can I find such information?

The case is not explicitly stated on cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt).

Comment: Please note that `undefined behavior` is not the same as `implementation-deﬁned result`. The former can literally make anything happen, the latter ensures that the result is documented in the compiler/architecture you are using (if it is compliant). As an example, `sizeof int` is implementation-defined, `*nullptr` is undefined

Comment: @pqnet: We all may know what you meant twith the last one, though I really want to point out that `*nullptr` is ill-formed, while `*(int*)nullptr` is UB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result is defined as 0 by the standard, [[bitset.members]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/template.bitset#bitset.members-9):

> bitset& operator>>=(size_t pos) noexcept;
>
> 9 Effects: Replaces each bit at position I in *this with a value
>   determined as follows:
>
> (9.1) If pos >= N - I, the new value is zero;
>
> (9.2) If pos < N - I, the new value is the previous value of the bit
>   at position I + pos.

Comment: And the same standard defines that `bitset<N> operator>>(size_t pos) const noexcept` returns `bitset<N>(*this) >>= pos` (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf, page 539).